# Switching power supply output capacitor

Tags: switching

Is there any rule or limitation for the capacitance in the output of a switching dc to dc step down regulator or PMICs?

I mean, could I put the double capacitance in the output to make sure the heavy load responses?

Comment: It depends on your circuit (which you haven't shown) but remember that what takes a long time to discharge takes a long time to recharge.

Comment: It's a general question. Also, when a power supply is capable to meet the worse case of the current, usually it is able to charge its capacitors too. Therefore the power rail should be stable in any extra capacitance. What do you mean it depends on your circuit? Could you please explain the cases when the extra capacitance may be harmful in power supplies?

Comment: To charge a bigger capacitor takes more energy, mostly a higher current. Take a big enough capacitor and the charging circuit might see it as a short and blow a fuse.

Comment: Unless the circuit contains ICs that implement slew rate. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If output capacitance is too large the power supply may shut down due to excessive charging current. This can affect supplies which have an over-current cutout. If the controller has a 'soft-start' function then you may be able to tune it to the higher capacitance.

Supplies which provide constant current or fold-back current limiting should work with any amount of extra capacitance, but the startup time will be longer. This might affect loads which need a fast rise time for proper initialization.

Some controllers rely on a minimum amount of capacitor ESR (Effective Series Resistance) for stability. If you increase capacitor size or add capacitors in parallel the ESR could become too low. For example the [LM2575](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2575-n.pdf) requires at least 0.05Ω to guarantee stability when running in continuous mode.

If you have a problem with voltage spikes during load current variations then you should add capacitance as close to the load as possible. This improves the effectiveness of the capacitor, while the resistance and inductance of the wires between it and the power supply provide some isolation.

Comment: I built a circuit with the TI's BQ25601 PMIC, datasheet recomended 20uF in the output. I put 3x10uF in the output and one 47uF ceramic after. I wonder if this could be an issue.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: According to Page 44: The charger device has internal loop compensation optimized for >20μF ceramic output capacitance. The
preferred ceramic capacitor is 10V rating, X7R or X5R. My setup is 3x10uF and one buck 47uF for handling extra heavy load steps. Works perfectly but I wanted to be sure...